The Screenshot Sharing Code isnt working on Xiaomi Redmi S2 and getting error like Legacy storage permissions not recommended for screenshots
`Below is the code i am taking SS and then sharing i get the correct path where SS is installing but facing error to share it on a whats app number directly though Intent.Chooser
public void shareScreenshot(File file, String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", file);
        // Create the intent to open the chat in WhatsApp Business
        Log.w("jarvis", "filepath" + uri.getEncodedPath());
        String whatsappInstalledPackage = isPackageExisted("com.whatsapp");
        Intent openChatIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        openChatIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://wa.me/" + phoneNumber));
        openChatIntent.setPackage(whatsappInstalledPackage);

        // Create the intent to share the screenshot
        Intent shareScreenshotIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareScreenshotIntent.setType("image/png");
        shareScreenshotIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        shareScreenshotIntent.putExtra("jid", phoneNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
        shareScreenshotIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareScreenshotIntent.setPackage(whatsappInstalledPackage);
        Log.w("jarvis", "check first done");
        startActivity(openChatIntent);
        finish();
        
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(()->{
        shareScreenshotIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareScreenshotIntent, "SS"));
            finish();
        }, 2000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ShareScreenshot", "Failure: " + e.getMessage());
        showToast("Error sharing screenshot");
    }
}


i have used two intents first one is for opening chat the other intent do cancel the first intent and start activity with carrying screenshot
